# Jupyter gets Import Error when importing matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter, enthought

I'm just now trying to integrate to Jupyter and I have been using Anaconda for a long while now.

When trying to import the matplotlib in the IPython Notebook,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

I get this error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-385145dcc870> in <module>()
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      2 get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib inline')

ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot
```

Comment: `rm -rf ~/Library/Enthought/`

Comment: Because removing the Canopy `Application` does not remove the folders in your home directory. https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy

Comment: I removed it then. Now when trying matplotlib again, i get this -- in edit.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. Then I used folllowing command to install matplotlib library to my virtual environment.

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Then I could import matplotlib to jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install `matplotlib` library if using conda then in terminal type:

```
# create a new environment with the required packages
conda create -n "matplotlib_build" python=3.5 numpy python-dateutil pyparsing pytz tornado cycler tk libpng zlib freetype
activate matplotlib_build
# if you want a qt backend, you also have to install pyqt (be aware that pyqt doesn't mix well if
# you have created the environment with conda-forge already activated...)
conda install pyqt
# this package is only available in the conda-forge channel
conda install -c conda-forge msinttypes

# copy the libs which have "wrong" names
set LIBRARY_LIB=%CONDA_PREFIX%\Library\lib
mkdir lib || cmd /c "exit /b 0"
copy %LIBRARY_LIB%\zlibstatic.lib lib\z.lib
copy %LIBRARY_LIB%\libpng_static.lib lib\png.lib

# Make the header files and the rest of the static libs available during the build
# CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV is a env variable which is set to the currently active environment path
set MPLBASEDIRLIST=%CONDA_PREFIX%\Library\;.

# build the wheel
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

This code was taken from https://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#conda-packages. Hope this helps.

Thanks

Michael